0x800f0954 error: Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed
While adding .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.8 features we are getting below error, maybe it is because of access/permission issue. we have newly created windows 2022 server
Don't know it is access/ permission issue or something else, apparently I have admin permission on the server.


I have come across the same error when installing OpenSSH Capability on Windows Server 2022. There are a couple of solutions suggested in Microsoft community for this. Following are 2 of them briefly.

Set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU  Registry key to 0.
Enabling download repair content and optional features directly from Windows Update using Local Group Policy Editor.

For a detailed explanation please refer to the following link.
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-0x800f0954-net-framework-3-5-optional-feature-dism/
